# Cannot recreate the database using EF-Code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to learn `EF Code first`. Initially I have tried all constraints using DataAnnotation on the ModelClass. And the work fine.
But now i am trying same using `Fluent API` With standalone configuration Files but It is unable to recreate the database and throwing this error

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

**Here is my Model**

```
public Class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my DbContext**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    //Public constructor to Call DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges method
    public AppContext()
    { 
        //Calling the Method to ReCreate the database
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AppContext>());
    }

    //Overriding OnModelCreating Method to Configure the Model using Fluent API
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Configuration.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}
```

**Here is my UserConfiguration Class**

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
     public UserConfiguration()
     {
          //Using Fluent API to configure Model
          HasKey(x => x.UserID);
          Property(x => x.Username).IsRequired().HasMaximumLength(50);
          Property(x => x.Password).IsRequired().HasMaximumLength(50);

     }
}
```

I Cannot figure out where I am Wrong. Any suggestion is appreciable.

**Note : I am using EF 4.3.1**

**Edit**
The `Fluent API` is working well if i put the configuration directly in the `OnModelCreating` method i.e

```
//Overriding OnModelCreating Method to Configure the Model using Fluent API
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         //Instead of Standalone Configuration file
         //modelBuilder.Configuration.Add(new UserConfiguration());

         //putting configuration here only
          modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(x => x.UserID);
          modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(x => x.Username).IsRequired().HasMaximumLength(50);
          modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(x => x.Password).IsRequired().HasMaximumLength(50);
    }
```

However i dont know the reason why its not working with standalone configuration file i.e `UserConfiguration` class.Any suggestion please

Comment: Delete the old database and try it again.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I have already tried it , but no luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was occurring in some other part of application, due to which database schema is created but the table `dbo._MigrationHistory` is unable to create on the sqlServer i.e is why the Codefirst is not able to drop the database coz the required info is not there. when i deleted the database it mst worked but i guess browers is showing the cached data. Everything is well when i restarted the system.